# Sitecore Not Finding Home Page

Tags: multisite, installation

This might be an obvious answer. I am setting up an existing site (website link changed, but still should point to the same directory) and I get the following error on the URL `notfound?item=%2f&user=sitecore%5cadmin&site=scheduler`.

This is Sitecore 8.1.

Any ideas on what I could of missed?

**Update:** It turned out to be a hosting issue. Not sure how it still made it into Sitecore, but that is what threw me off.

Comment: Rob, can you add some details to your question? A screenshot or paste of your `<site>` node maybe?

Comment: Try adding `?sc_site=website` to the URL. That said, have you modified your [**site configuration**](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx) in Sitecore.config, or as a config patch file?

Answer (score 9):

Your website is not set up correctly in the `<site>` config node of the web.config

1. Try to load `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and search for `<sites>`
2. Within `<sites>` look for the `<site>` node that defines your website (this will be the one with the `rootPath` attribute pointing to the Sitecore content root item for your site)
3. Verify the `hostName` attribute. This should be either the host name you are using to access your website or not defined (in that case it's a wildcard and will listen to all host names). Note that if it's a wildcard, you should set the `targetHostName` attribute, otherwise Sitecore doesn't know how to generate links on your site.

If this does not help, you should revise your question and provide us with more details as requested in the comments.